# Correct SQL Query with a JOIN and NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a SQL Query that shows me **all polls** a user (uid) has **not voted** yet.

Example:

- There are pid 1, 2 and 3
- uid 1 voted on poll 1 and 3

So I need the query that shows me the pid 2 he didnt vote yet.

This are the 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `poll` (
`pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`deadline` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
`vid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`uid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`votes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`vid`),
KEY `pcid` (`pid`,`uid`),
KEY `uid` (`uid`),
KEY `tid` (`tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

//edit this should make it more clear

Constraints for table `votes`

```
ALTER TABLE `votes`
ADD CONSTRAINT `votes_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `poll` (`pid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `votes_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `user` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `votes_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`tid`) REFERENCES `teams` (`tid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Can smbdy please help me. I guess it is a join with a WHERE and NOT LIKE but I just dont get it.

Merci!

Comment: You're looking for right join.

Comment: can you please comment on your code exactly what each column on the database means so its easier to work with

Comment: what are these thing? `vid`,
`pid`,
`uid`,
`tid`

Comment: Some fields are obvious: pid = poll id, vid = votes id. The uid and tid are the ones that can't be guessed, I suspect they are not needed to help with this question.

Comment: i assume uid is user? its just that most people don't want to go round deciphering code

Comment: I added the Constraints to make to make it more clear.
@martijn answered already the right query, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay so this is my first answer. There might me more possibilities, but this should work.

```
SELECT * FROM Poll WHERE pid NOT IN (SELECT pid FROM votes WHERE uid = 1);
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work as I don't know the database type from which you're trying to retrieve your data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    [poll].*
FROM
    [poll]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [votes]
        ON [votes].[pid] = [poll].[pid]
        AND [votes].[uid] = @uid
WHERE
    [votes].[vid] IS NULL
```

Comment: The outer join retains all poll records whether or not there was a vote on that poll from the specified user. The where clause removes all poll records WITH a vote.

Comment: Oops! Yeah, I just typed it out of hand without creating the tables or anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  p.*
From
  poll p
Where
  Not Exists (
    Select 
      'x'
    From
      Votes v
    Where
      v.pid = p.pid and
      v.uid = <myuidvalue>
  )
```